# how to set bulk_options in openrowset to read file from Azure blob storage?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, openrowset

I have an Azure SQL database and would like to read a csv file from Azure blob storage (gen 2) with openrowset. However, the output lacks proper formatting, as rows and columns are not separated.

In the csv file, FIELD TERMINATOR is '|' and ROW TERMINATOR is '0x0a'.
I've used openrowset to read the file, my code is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
OPENROWSET 
( 
    BULK '/myPath/myFile.csv'
    ,DATA_SOURCE = 'myDataSource'
    ,SINGLE_CLOB    
)  
AS fct
```

the problem is the result is in only one field and when I use

```
,FIELDTERMINATOR ='|'
,ROWTERMINATOR ='0x0a'
```

I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'FIELDTERMINATOR'.

How can I read the file in table format.
I tried to create the format file based on a table that is similar to csv file in landing zone, when I run the following command in windows cmd in my client:
bcp myAzureDB.mySchema.myTable format nul -f "https://myBlobStorage/myPath/filename.fmt" -S HPESTAR -c -T.
I got this error" A valid table name is required for in, out, or format options. That I'm sure the table name  is correct.

Comment: A quick look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) will tell you there is no `FIELDTERMINATOR` or `ROWTERMINATOR` option. You likely want to use a [Format File](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server) here in you must use `OPENROWSET`. If you want to *import* the data, then you can use a [`BULK INSERT`](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql), which does allow definition of the terminators.

Comment: I don't want to import the data, so I don't want to use Bulk Insert. The issue is How to use format files in a cloud setting.

Comment: You would place the format file in the Azure Blob Storage, just like the CSV file.

Comment: I also tried STRING_SPLIT, but it only split rows, not columns:

SELECT CAST(LIST_DATA.VALUE AS VARCHAR(max)) AS PKG_LIST  
FROM 
OPENROWSET 
( 
 BULK '/myPath/myFile.csv'
 ,DATA_SOURCE = 'myDataSource'
 ,SINGLE_CLOB 
)  
AS fct
CROSS APPLY
    STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(fct.BulkColumn, CHAR(10), 'þ'), CHAR(13), ''), 'þ') AS LIST_DATA;

Comment: Correct, `STRING_SPLIT` splits a delimited value into *rows* not columns. If you *did* use `STRING_SPLIT` you'd have to then `PIVOT` your data afterwards.

Comment: Is there any appropriate guidance for creating format files in Azure? I see there are some of them for SQL server but for the cloud, I didn't find anything.

Comment: Format files look identical whether they are hosted in the cloud or not, Sara. The documentation I link above demonstrates what it should look like; that you are going to save that file to Azure Blob Storage doesn't change that.

Comment: I've already read the documents, for creating format file and using it, all the "path" are local and I don't how to change them to cloud

Comment: Did you have a read of [Examples of Bulk Access to Data in Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver16) which is referenced in the above linked documentation? The very first example demonstrates the use of a format file.

Comment: Thanks for your time but unfortunately I didn't get the appropriate answer.

Comment: So what about the documentation didn't you understand? Explain where you got stuck by [edit]ing your question and what about the linked documentation you were unable to implement.

Comment: I can't create the format file based on a csv file in landing zone.

Comment: *Why* can't you? Again, explain that in the question.

Comment: I've explained more in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try following command in Your command prompt to get format file.**

```
bcp <database_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name> format nul -f <output_file_name> -c -S <server_name>.database.windows.net -U <username> -P <password>
```

[image]

It will get you file downloaded locally from Azure SQL Database.

[image]

then upload this file to blob storage in similar container and update the terminators as your requirement.

[image]

**Code to read CSV file:**

```sql
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'fsn2p/Book1.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
   FORMAT = 'CSV',
   FORMATFILE='fsn2p/format.fmt',
   FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices'
   ) AS DataFile;
```

***Output***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The bcp command did not work for me due to security policies in our cloud environment. The login failed.

```
bcp <database_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name> format nul -f <output_file_name> -c -S <server_name>.database.windows.net -U <username> -P <password>
```

So, I copied the table into my local SQL server and generated a formatfile based on the local database. I could, however, make the formatfile manually.